# Quick Archimedean Property Question. Sequence Convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, upper-lower-bounds

Say I have a sequence {${x_n}$} that converges to $x$, that I know is consisting of nonzero, real numbers. Then can I say, by Q being dense in R, that there exists a rational number q, such that for all $x_n$ , $0<q<|x_n|$?

I need this for a larger proof.

Thanks

Comment: Im assuming $x>0$? Otherwise this wont necessarily be true, as $x_n=\frac1n$ is a counterexample sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You are are assuming each $x_n\neq0$. If you also assume $x\neq0$, then such a $q$ does exist.

*Proof*: Let $\epsilon=x/2$. Note that $x_n\to x$ implies that $|x_n|\to |x|$ (proof this!).

Therefore, there is an $N$ so that for all $n\ge N$, $||x|-|x_n||<\epsilon$, which implies $|x|/2\le |x_n|$ when $n\ge N$. Now, let $y=\min(|x_1|,|x_2|,\dots,|x_N|,|x|/2)$. Then it follows that $y\le |x_n|$ for *all* $n$, not just $n\ge N$. Therefore, choosing any rational number in the interval $(0,y)$ would suffice.

Comment: Yes, in the proof I'm doing. I know $x$ is nonzero, and I know $x_n$ is always nonzero. Sorry for expanding such a simple question, I'm just a little uneasy to do this as it will make my assigned proof suspiciously easy

Comment: @Mercury Perhaps proving such a $q$ exists is supposed to be the hard part of the exercise. Coming up with the above argument is certainly not too easy, depending on how much analysis you know.

Comment: I understand your proof and how you reached it. However, is it necessary if all I need to prove, is that there is a real number $q$ such that $0<q<|x_n|$? It seems like the simple fact that $x$ and $x_n$ are nonzero should be enough to just state that such a q exists with Archimedean property. The fact that it converges doesn't even seem necessary

Comment: Also, $x$ could have been negative. So how do you show that $y$ is guaranteed to be positive?

Comment: Here's why you need convergence: let $x_n=1/n$, and $x=1$. Then no such $q$ exists, because there is no rational number which is smaller than $1/n$ for all $n$. Also, $x$ cannot be negative: how could you have a sequence of positive numbers converge to a negative number?

Comment: I don't have a sequence of positive numbers, I have a sequence of nonzero numbers. Thinking about it though, I think your proof is still okay. Except that you would have that $|x/2|<=|x_n|$ which can still complete this part of the proof as $q$ only needs to be smaller than the absolute value of every number in the sequence. Does this explanation make sense?

Comment: My mistake, I misread your problem statement. The proof is now fixed and works when $x<0$. The solution was to put absolute value signs around everything.

Comment: Back to your comment about why convergence is necessary; in the example you provided, that sequence would have a limit of zero, which we know $x$ is not equal to.

Comment: Exactly. This means $x_n$ does not converge to $x$, proving that the conclusion you want does not always occur without the assumption that $x_n\to x$ for some $x\neq0$.